# How to select a folder through a dialog and process all the files it contains

Tags: c#, excel

I want to read xlsx files one by one from a folder. I am currently using a button to browse a single file but I want to use this button to browse the folder in which I have the files. So, when I select this folder the program should automatically run all the files in the folder, one by one.

Here is my code:

```
class RatWalk 
{ 
    public List steps = new List();

    // reads data from excel file
    public void LoadFromFile(String fileName)                       
    {
        steps.Clear();

        XlsFile file = new XlsFile(fileName);
        try
        {
            //everything I want to do
        }
        catch
        {
        } 
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()                             
    {
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(OnClick);
        button.Text = "Browse for the XLS file";                    
        // button properties                                       
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    // Browses for the file and loads the selected Excel file
    private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)            
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;
        ratWalk.LoadFromFile(fileDialog.FileName);

        // Whatever I want to do   
    }
}
```

I want to change it in such a way that when I click the button and select the folder it runs all the files in the folder one by one.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for each xlsx files in the selected folder :

```
string selectedFolder = string.Empty;
        FolderBrowserDialog selectFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (selectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            selectedFolder = selectFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(selectedFolder);
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles("*.xlsx"))
            {
                ratWalk.LoadFromFile(file.FullName);
                //
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this. this would be helpful

```
 FolderBrowserDialog fi = new FolderBrowserDialog();
 DialogResult result = fi.ShowDialog();
 if (result == DialogResult.OK)
 {
   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fi.SelectedPath);
 }
```

files array contain all the files in the folder.
Use the files array for your process...